# date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta') not working

Tags: php, hosting, web-hosting

My site hosted in 1and1.Now the problem is time when insert values to database the US timezone is insert.not INDIA timezone. but i insert this function above file

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$x=insert into add_trans(date,time,emp_id)values(NOW(),CURTIME(),'".$_SESSION['uid']."');
```

Comment: you have to change the timezone of your `*sql` too.  for mysql look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: after running this query SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone; and i am get SYSTEM as the result

Comment: when i try this its working good, but after include with my site its not working. i think the problem may be CURTIME()

Comment: <?php
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time()) . "\n";
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time()) . "\n";
?>

Comment: above code working in online and localhost. but here CURTIME() not used so in my view thats the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
$x=INSET INTO add_trans (date, time, emp_id)
   VALUES (date('d-m-Y'), date('H:i:s'), '".$_SESSION['uid']."');
```

(Change the format in `date` function as stored in DB)

Comment: no its not working because here we can not change the any timezone

Comment: Before that do the same code you've done: `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');`

Comment: What's wrong? the date isn't Calcutta time? Check this snippet [here](https://ideone.com/42fBKA)

Comment: yes its working but when i insert into DB (1and1 host provider) its not working

Answer (score 2):

Try changing "date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');" to following;

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

This may work! Let us know